# Подключить moment.js к Angular2

Tags: angular2, momentjs

Помогите подключить momen.js вк проекту angular 2, я новичек.

Я установил moment с помощью npm install --save moment.
Вот мой файл app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

let myMoment: moment.Moment = moment("someDate");

let now = moment("2014/04/25");
let date = now.format('LLLL');

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Браузер выдает такое сообщение : 
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Что я делаю не правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Это не ошибка, а предупреждение об устаревшем формате даты. И в скором обновлении текущий формат даты не будет поддерживаться.

В твоем случает это "2014/04/25".

Поддерживаемые форматы: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Comment: можешь в консоли http://momentjs.com/ ввести `moment("2014/04/25")`